# Swift5 UIView rotation behavior different for iPhone vs iPad

Tags: swift, iphone, ipad, rotation, difference

I have struggled with odd differences in behavior between iPhone and iPad (both in simulators as well as real devices) and despite trying different ways to diagnosis this with many visits to Stackoverflow, I am still struggling to get to a root cause. Specifically, I have a simple Test view controller that performs as expected with iPad but the same code behaves differently and not as expected on iPhone. I have one UIImageView centered on each device in portrait mode with 10px margins left, right and top. When I rotate the device, the objective is to resize the image in landscape so it remains 10px for these margins IE it gets scaled to fit the new geometry and the image always appears in its original orientation. The iPad does this perfectly without a lot of code. However the iPhone performs the scaling correctly but the image does not stay in its original orientation ... it rotates with the device rotation. How can the same code produce two different results?

I can solve this by detecting iPhone and writing code to rotate the image and determine the new origin for placement, in fact I have this working. However, it doesn't seem right to me to have different logic for iPhone versus iPad.

Some details: I am using Swift 5 Xcode 12 MacOS 10.15.6 Simulator 11.5 iPhone 11 with IOS 14.0.1 and iPad 7th Gen IOS 14.0.1

Using interface builder to build layout initially and linking to code with IBOutlet however I am  using translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and anchor constraints programmatically to place the UIImageView. I am using Notification Center to add and remove an observer to trigger rotation events. I am using begin and endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications(). I override shouldAutorotate as true, supportedInterfaceOrientations as all, and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation as portrait my Test VC as well as creating extensions for UINavigationController and UITabBarController in SceneDelegate to propagate these values given Test VC is embedded in a Nav Controller and uses tab bar. Info plist lists all 4 modes for supported interface orientations and the general tab for the Xcode project selects iPhone and iPad as deployable and all 4 orientation modes are unselected for Device Orientation.

I can add code here if helpful as well as screenshots. If anyone has had a similar experience or any ideas about this I would be grateful! Here is the code for TestVC:

```
import UIKit

class Test: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var testImage: UIImageView!
    
    let debug = true
    let program = "TestViewController"
    var deviceSize = CGRect.zero
    var deviceWidth: CGFloat = 0
    var deviceHeight: CGFloat = 0
    let imageAsset = UIImage(named: "Cera.jpg")
    var aspectRatio: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool { return true }
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all }
    override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation { return UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait }
    
    // This routine triggered the first time this view controiller is loaded
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let rtn = "viewDidLoad"
        top = self.view.topAnchor
        lead = self.view.leadingAnchor
        deviceSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        deviceWidth = deviceSize.width
        deviceHeight = deviceSize.height
        
        UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceRotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        
        if debug { print(">>> \(program): \(rtn): device width[\(deviceWidth)] device height[\(deviceHeight)]") }
        determineOrientation()
        if debug { print(">>> \(program): \(rtn): rotated device width[\(rotatedDeviceWidth)] rotated device height[\(rotatedDeviceHeight)]") }
        testImage.image = imageAsset
        let imageWidth = testImage.image!.size.width
        let imageHeight = testImage.image!.size.height
        aspectRatio = imageHeight / imageWidth
        calculateContraints()
    }
    
    // This routine triggered every time this view controller is presented
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let rtn = "viewWillAppear"
        if debug { print(">>> \(program): \(rtn): device width[\(deviceWidth)] device height[\(deviceHeight)]") }
        determineOrientation()
        if debug { print(">>> \(program): \(rtn): rotated device width[\(rotatedDeviceWidth)] rotated device height[\(rotatedDeviceHeight)]") }
    }
    
    // This routine added to remove observer for rotation events
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        UIDevice.current.endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    }
    
    var orientation = "Portrait"
    var rotatedDeviceWidth: CGFloat = 0
    var rotatedDeviceHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    // This routine called by "viewWillTransition" to determoine "orientation" value
    func determineOrientation() {
        let rtn = "determineOrientation"
        if debug { print(">>> \(program): \(rtn)") }
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait { orientation = "Portrait" }
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft { orientation = "LandscapeLeft" }
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight { orientation = "LandscapeRight" }
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown { orientation = "PortraitUpsideDown" }
        if orientation == "Portrait" || orientation == "PortraitUpsideDown" {
            rotatedDeviceWidth = deviceWidth
            rotatedDeviceHeight = deviceHeight
        } else {
            rotatedDeviceWidth = deviceHeight
            rotatedDeviceHeight = deviceWidth
        }
    }
    
    var imageWidth: CGFloat = 0
    var imageHeight: CGFloat = 0
    var imageXpos: CGFloat = 0
    var imageYpos: CGFloat = 0
    var v: CGFloat = 0
    var h: CGFloat = 0
    var w: CGFloat = 0
    var ht: CGFloat = 0
    
    // This routine determines the position of the display object "testImage"
    func calculateContraints() {
        let rtn = "calculateContraints"
        if debug { print(">>> \(program): \(rtn): orientation[\(orientation)]") }
        if orientation == "Portrait" {
            imageWidth = deviceWidth / 2 - 20
            imageHeight = imageWidth * CGFloat(aspectRatio)
            imageXpos = 10
            imageYpos = 10
            if debug { print(">>> \(imageWidth): \(imageHeight)") }
        }
        if orientation == "LandscapeLeft" {
            imageWidth = rotatedDeviceWidth / 2 - 20
            imageHeight = imageWidth * CGFloat(aspectRatio)
            imageXpos = 10
            imageYpos = 10
            if debug { print(">>> \(imageWidth): \(imageHeight)") }
        }
        if orientation == "LandscapeRight" {
            imageWidth = rotatedDeviceWidth / 2 - 20
            imageHeight = imageWidth * CGFloat(aspectRatio)
            imageXpos = 10
            imageYpos = 10
            if debug { print(">>> \(imageWidth): \(imageHeight)") }
        }
        if orientation == "PortraitUpsideDown" {
            imageWidth = deviceWidth / 2 - 20
            imageHeight = imageWidth * CGFloat(aspectRatio)
            imageXpos = 10
            imageYpos = 10
            if debug { print(">>> \(imageWidth): \(imageHeight)") }
        }
        layoutConstraints(v: imageXpos, h: imageYpos, w: imageWidth, ht: imageHeight)
    }
    
    var testImageTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var testImageLeftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var testImageWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var testImageHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor!
    var lead: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor!
    var trail: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor!
    var bot: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor!
    
    // This routine lays out the display object "testImage"
    func layoutConstraints(v: CGFloat, h: CGFloat, w: CGFloat, ht: CGFloat) {
        let rtn = "layoutConstraints"
        if debug { print(">>> \(program): \(rtn)") }
        testImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if testImageTopConstraint != nil { testImageTopConstraint.isActive = false }
        if testImageLeftConstraint != nil { testImageLeftConstraint.isActive = false }
        if testImageWidthConstraint != nil { testImageWidthConstraint.isActive = false }
        if testImageHeightConstraint != nil { testImageHeightConstraint.isActive = false }
        testImageTopConstraint = testImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: v)
        testImageLeftConstraint = testImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lead, constant: h)
        testImageWidthConstraint = testImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: w)
        testImageHeightConstraint = testImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: ht)
        testImageTopConstraint.isActive = true
        testImageLeftConstraint.isActive = true
        testImageWidthConstraint.isActive = true
        testImageHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    }
}

@objc extension Test {
    func deviceRotated(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        let device = notification.object as! UIDevice
        let deviceOrientation = device.orientation
        switch deviceOrientation {
        case .landscapeLeft: print("<<<Landscape Left>>>")
        case .landscapeRight: print("<<<Landscape Right>>>")
        case .portrait: print("<<<Portrait>>>")
        case .portraitUpsideDown: print("<<<Portrait Upside Down>>>")
        case .faceDown: print("<<<Face Down>>>")
        case .faceUp: print("<<<Face Up>>>")
        case .unknown: print("<<<Unknown>>>")
        @unknown default: print("<<<Default>>>")
        }
        let rtn = "deviceRotated2"
        determineOrientation()
        if debug { print(">>> \(program): \(rtn): Device rotated to: \(orientation)") }
        if debug { print(">>> \(program): \(rtn): rotated device width[\(rotatedDeviceWidth)] rotated device height[\(rotatedDeviceHeight)]") }
        calculateContraints()
    }
}
```

Here is the code in SceneDelegate.swift

```
extension UINavigationController {
    
    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        get {
            if let visibleVC = visibleViewController { return visibleVC.shouldAutorotate }
            return super.shouldAutorotate } }
    
    override open var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        get {
            if let visibleVC = visibleViewController { return visibleVC.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation }
            return super.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation } }
    
    override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        get {
            if let visibleVC = visibleViewController { return visibleVC.supportedInterfaceOrientations }
            return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations } }
}

// ===================================================================================
// UITabBarController Extension - used to manage tab bar style
//
extension UITabBarController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return selectedViewController?.childForStatusBarStyle ?? selectedViewController
    }
}

// ===================================================================================
// UITabBarController Extension - used to manage rotation
//
extension UITabBarController {
    
    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        if let viewController = self.viewControllers?[self.selectedIndex] { return viewController.shouldAutorotate }
        return super.shouldAutorotate }
    
    override open var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        if let viewController = self.viewControllers?[self.selectedIndex] { return viewController.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation }
        return super.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation }
    
    override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if let viewController = self.viewControllers?[self.selectedIndex] { return viewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations }
        return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations }
}
```

Here are the rotation results for the iPhone in the simulator:
[Cera rotations for iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ORAG.png)

... and iPad:
[Cera rotations for iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52UMi.png)

Comment: Please add some screenshots!

Comment: I am going to remove the IBOutlet and create the UIImageView object programmatically on a hunch this may be the cause ... not sure why, but it's probably worth the effort. Will update this post with what I learn. Still makes no sense to me iPad works and iPhone doesn't with very same code.